# Minitest & Webdrivers: unable to connect to chromedriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-chromedriver, minitest

**Background:**

Rails 5.x / Ruby 2.6.3 app on MacOSX

I am new to system integration tests and until have just done basic controller tests.

**What I Am Doing**

My gemfile is like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

and I installed chromedriver from Brew and running like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver --verbose --port=9516
```

I have commented out all the auto-generated tests and left a basic on that just visits an index page etc.

**Problems**

My tests fail with:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
```

If I switch the `chromedriver` port the test fails with another port (9516/9516).

**Question**

Anything obvious here or am I doing this completely wrong?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer below I have done the following:

- ditched the brew install
- as per the manual and answer below added to my `test_helper.rb`:

  module ActionDispatch
  class IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL
  # Make `assert_*` methods behave like Minitest assertions
  include Capybara::Minitest::Assertions

  ```
    # Reset sessions and driver between tests
    teardown do
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
      Capybara.use_default_driver
    end

    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
    setup do
      Capybara.server = :thin
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
    end
  end
  ```

  end

test still fails with:

```
#<Thread:0x00007ff6f88922f8@/Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.35.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:76 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.35.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:77:in `block in boot': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
#<Thread:0x00007ff6f8068528@/Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.35.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:76 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.35.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:77:in `block in boot': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
ERROR["test_visiting_the_index", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007ff6f7a48d50 @name="WellsTest">, 10.740007999993395]
 test_visiting_the_index#WellsTest (10.74s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
            /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.35.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:77:in `block in boot'
```

**UPDATE 2**

thin is not supported - switched to puma: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2448

12:31:39 - INFO - Running: test/system/work_breakdown_structures_test.rb
Started with run options --seed 43168

```
Capybara starting Puma...--=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=] 0% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: ??:??:??
* Version 5.2.0 , codename: Fettisdagsbulle
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:60707
ERROR["test_visiting_the_index", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007fcafb268068 @name="WorkBreakdownStructuresTest">, 73.58754300000146]
 test_visiting_the_index#WorkBreakdownStructuresTest (73.59s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
            test/system/work_breakdown_structures_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:WorkBreakdownStructuresTest>'

  1/1: [==============================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:01:13, Time: 00:01:13

Finished in 73.58843s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Tried this `Capybara.server_port = 60707` but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing a couple steps missing.

1. You shouldn't be installing chromedriver from brew, you can use the "webdrivers" gem to handle that. The gem will install drivers in the `~/.webdrivers` directory by default.
2. When running integration tests, you'll need to set the proper driver for Capybara. https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selenium

`Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome`

Comment: Getting close with your answer.  Added that then got complaints about `Capybara.server`.  Added `Capybara.server = :thin`

Comment: Now I get: Minitest::UnexpectedError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
            /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.35.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:77:in `block in boot'

Comment: Googling this error now - nothing obvious yet.

Comment: The other issue was I should have picked puma.  https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2448

Answer (score 0):

Very stupid and non-obvious issue - the gems need to be in the `test` group ‍♂️:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```